# How to resolve the internet browser issue in High Maps?

Tags: highcharts

Map is showing in all browsers like chrome,Firefox but the map is not showing in IE 11,this code is working in chrome but its not working in IE11 once add the load event and loop the data,answer is appreciable? but its working in chrome if i use load event also

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/index.js?1"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/maps/demo/all-maps/jquery.combobox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var mapData = Highcharts.maps['custom/world'];
      var data = [{"Name": "Australia","status": "Live"}];
      $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        chart: {
          events: {
            load: function() {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.series[1].data.length; i++) {
                  this.series[0].data.forEach((el) => {
     if (el['name'] == this.series[1].data[i].Name) {
      if(this.series[1].data[i].status == 'Live'){
       el.update({color: "lightgreen"});
      }
     }
     return el
    })
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Countries',
          mapData: mapData,
        }, {
          name: 'Countries options',
          visible: false,
          data: data
        }]
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Nayeem Shaiky, could you please add more detail to your question?

Comment: Hi @toti08 what u need..?

Comment: working fine for me in IE and chrome both.

Comment: Just like the others. Works fine on Chrome and IE11. Please describe more precise what problem exactly do you have?

Comment: If i use load event then its not working...

Comment: @Nayeem Shaiky because you are using arrow functions which are not supported in IE11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - you are using arrow function which is not supported in IE11: caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

If you want to make your code working on IE11, it is not enough to change arrow function to normal function, because you will have different **this**. Using arrow function your **this** is the same **this** like in your load() function. But when you define a normal function() (instead of arrow function), your **this** will be changed. That's why you need to define *var chart = this;* in your load() function and replace **this** to **chart** in few places. Here you have working code:

```
chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this;
          for (let i = 0; i < this.series[1].data.length; i++) {
              this.series[0].data.forEach(function(el) {
                if (el['name'] == chart.series[1].data[i].Name) {
                    if(chart.series[1].data[i].status == 'Live'){
                        el.update({color: "lightgreen"});
                    }
                }
                return el
            })
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Working IE11 demo: https://codepen.io/raf18seb/full/RYjavx/